# Can I get a list of Stripe subscriptions with multiple statuses?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm using:

```
    const stripeCustomerSubscriptions = await stripe.subscriptions.list({
        customer: req.body.stripeCustomerId,
        status: 'active'
    });
```

and that gets me all `active` subscriptions. But I want all `active` and `trialing`. Any way to specify both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [strip API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list) if we want to retrieve more than one status we should specify "all" in the status field and filter the results that we get back by ourselves.

The code should look something like:

```
const stripeCustomerSubscriptions = await stripe.subscriptions.list({
        customer: req.body.stripeCustomerId,
        status: 'all'
    });

const filteredSubs = stripeCustomerSubscriptions.data.filter(sub => sub.status === 'active' || sub.status === 'trialing');
```

Comment: This is correct - you would need to list `all` and then filter the received data. You cannot list for multiple status values explicitly.